# Jquery - Cycle plugin - zero elements found by selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery code like this:

```
$j(function(){

        $j('.slideContent').cycle({ 

            fx:     slideFx, 

            speed:  'slow', 

            timeout: slide_auto, 

            rev:     reV,

            pauseOnPagerHover: 1,

            pause: 1,

            pager:  '.slideTab', 

            prev: '.slideshow .prev',

            next: '.slideshow .next',

            pagerEvent: 'mouseover',

            pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 

                return '.slideTab li:eq(' + idx + ')'; 

                $j('.activeSlide').find('.arrowActive').show(); 

            } 

        });

});
```

The error I am getting is:

```
[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector
```

Another error I am getting from the same code:

```
unreachable code after return statement
```

Comment: Need to see your html

Comment: log $j('.slideContent').length, ...do you see a number greater than 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error, "zero elements found by selector" is most likely referring to this line:

`$j('.slideContent')`

Please check that you have an html element with the class "slideContent" (for id you may need to change selector to `$j('#slideContent')`).

The error, `unreachable code after return statement` is referring to this line:

`$j('.activeSlide').find('.arrowActive').show();`

which occurs directly under a return statement. When this code executes the return will break out of the loop, and that line will not be run. Please move it above the return statement.